Problem unmarshalling a json array in spring boot
I'm trying to unmarshall the json array from https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/25/encounters, here it's the resume version:
[
  {
    "location_area": {
      "name": "sinnoh-route-218-area",
      "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/location-area/168/"
    }
  },
  {
    "location_area": {
      "name": "johto-route-34-area",
      "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/location-area/205/"
    
  }
]

I tried with this:
restTemplate.exchange("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/25/encounters", HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<LocationAreaEncounters>(){
        })

but throws me the next error:
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type com.bankaya.pokemon.dto.LocationAreaEncounters from Array value (token JsonToken.START_ARRAY)
at [Source: REDACTED (StreamReadFeature.INCLUDE_SOURCE_IN_LOCATION disabled); line: 1, column: 1]
These are my classes:
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class LocationAreaEncounters {
    
    @JsonProperty("location_area")
    private List<Location_Area> locationArea;

}


@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonRootName("location_area")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Location_Area {

    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("url")
    private String url;
    
}

Also tried with:
restTemplate.exchange("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/25/encounters", HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Location_Area>>(){
        })

this retrieves the correct number of objects but with null values.
"locationAreas": [
        {
            "name": null,
            "url": null
        }
    ],

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you for your help.

The class LocationAreaEncounters is not Array and should be deserialized as JSONObject.

Use another method
    @Test
    void test() {
        List<Location_Area> result = restTemplate.getForObject("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/25/encounters", List.class);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
 
}
// [{location_area={name=trophy-garden-area, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/location-area/118/}, version_details=[{encounter_details=[{chance=5, condition_values=[], max_level=18, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=18}, {chance=4, condition_values=[], max_level=18, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=18}, {chance=1, condition_values=[], max_level=18, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=18}], max_chance=10, version={name=diamond, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/12/}}, {encounter_details=[{chance=5, condition_values=[], max_level=18, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=18}, {chance=4, condition_values=[], max_level=18, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=18}, {chance=1, condition_values=[], max_level=18, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=18}], max_chance=10, version={name=pearl, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/13/}}, {encounter_details=[{chance=5, condition_values=[], max_level=22, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=22}, {chance=4, condition_values=[], max_level=24, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=24}, {chance=1, condition_values=[], max_level=24, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=24}], max_chance=10, version={name=platinum, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/14/}}]}, {location_area={name=pallet-town-area, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/location-area/285/}, version_details=[{encounter_details=[{chance=100, condition_values=[], max_level=5, method={name=gift, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/18/}, min_level=5}], max_chance=100, version={name=yellow, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/3/}}]}, {location_area={name=kanto-route-2-south-towards-viridian-city, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/location-area/296/}, version_details=[{encounter_details=[{chance=4, condition_values=[{name=time-day, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-condition-value/4/}], max_level=4, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=4}, {chance=4, condition_values=[{name=time-morning, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-condition-value/3/}], max_level=4, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=4}, {chance=4, condition_values=[{name=time-night, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-condition-value/5/}], max_level=4, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=4}, {chance=1, condition_values=[{name=time-day, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-condition-value/4/}], max_level=4, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=4}, {chance=1, condition_values=[{name=time-morning, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-condition-value/3/}], max_level=4, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=4}, {chance=1, condition_values=[{name=time-night, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-condition-value/5/}], max_level=4, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=4}], max_chance=15, version={name=gold, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/4/}}, {encounter_details=[{chance=4, condition_values=[{name=time-day, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-condition-value/4/}], max_level=4, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=4}, {chance=4, condition_values=[{name=time-morning, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-condition-value/3/}], max_level=4, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=4}, {chance=4, condition_values=[{name=time-night, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-condition-value/5/}], max_level=4, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=4}, {chance=1, condition_values=[{name=time-day, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-condition-value/4/}], max_level=4, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=4}, {chance=1, condition_values=[{name=time-morning, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-condition-value/3/}], max_level=4, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=4}, {chance=1, condition_values=[{name=time-night, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-condition-value/5/}], max_level=4, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=4}], max_chance=15, version={name=silver, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/5/}}, {encounter_details=[{chance=4, condition_values=[{name=time-day, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-condition-value/4/}], max_level=4, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=4}, {chance=4, condition_values=[{name=time-morning, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-condition-value/3/}], max_level=4, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=4}, {chance=1, condition_values=[{name=time-day, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-condition-value/4/}], max_level=4, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=4}, {chance=1, condition_values=[{name=time-morning, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-condition-value/3/}], max_level=4, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=4}], max_chance=10, version={name=crystal, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/6/}}]}, {location_area={name=viridian-forest-area, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/location-area/321/}, version_details=[{encounter_details=[{chance=4, condition_values=[], max_level=3, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=3}, {chance=1, condition_values=[], max_level=5, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=5}], max_chance=5, version={name=red, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/1/}}, {encounter_details=[{chance=4, condition_values=[], max_level=3, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=3}, {chance=1, condition_values=[], max_level=5, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=5}], max_chance=5, version={name=blue, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/2/}}, {encounter_details=[{chance=4, condition_values=[], max_level=3, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=3}, {chance=1, condition_values=[], max_level=5, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=5}], max_chance=5, version={name=firered, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/10/}}, {encounter_details=[{chance=4, condition_values=[], max_level=3, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=3}, {chance=1, condition_values=[], max_level=5, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=5}], max_chance=5, version={name=leafgreen, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/11/}}, {encounter_details=[{chance=4, condition_values=[], max_level=4, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=4}, {chance=1, condition_values=[{name=time-morning, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-condition-value/3/}], max_level=7, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=7}, {chance=1, condition_values=[{name=time-day, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-condition-value/4/}], max_level=7, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=7}, {chance=1, condition_values=[], max_level=4, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=4}], max_chance=7, version={name=heartgold, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/15/}}, {encounter_details=[{chance=4, condition_values=[], max_level=4, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=4}, {chance=1, condition_values=[{name=time-morning, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-condition-value/3/}], max_level=7, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=7}, {chance=1, condition_values=[{name=time-day, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-condition-value/4/}], max_level=7, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=7}, {chance=1, condition_values=[], max_level=4, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=4}], max_chance=7, version={name=soulsilver, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/16/}}]}, {location_area={name=power-plant-area, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/location-area/330/}, version_details=[{encounter_details=[{chance=15, condition_values=[], max_level=20, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=20}, {chance=10, condition_values=[], max_level=24, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=24}], max_chance=25, version={name=red, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/1/}}, {encounter_details=[{chance=15, condition_values=[], max_level=20, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=20}, {chance=10, condition_values=[], max_level=24, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=24}], max_chance=25, version={name=blue, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/2/}}, {encounter_details=[{chance=10, condition_values=[], max_level=22, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=22}, {chance=10, condition_values=[], max_level=24, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=24}, {chance=4, condition_values=[], max_level=26, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=26}, {chance=1, condition_values=[], max_level=26, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=26}], max_chance=25, version={name=firered, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/10/}}, {encounter_details=[{chance=10, condition_values=[], max_level=22, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=22}, {chance=10, condition_values=[], max_level=24, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=24}, {chance=4, condition_values=[], max_level=26, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=26}, {chance=1, condition_values=[], max_level=26, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=26}], max_chance=25, version={name=leafgreen, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/11/}}]}, {location_area={name=hoenn-safari-zone-sw, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/location-area/431/}, version_details=[{encounter_details=[{chance=4, condition_values=[], max_level=25, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=25}, {chance=1, condition_values=[], max_level=27, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=27}], max_chance=5, version={name=ruby, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/7/}}, {encounter_details=[{chance=4, condition_values=[], max_level=25, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=25}, {chance=1, condition_values=[], max_level=27, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=27}], max_chance=5, version={name=sapphire, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/8/}}, {encounter_details=[{chance=4, condition_values=[], max_level=25, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=25}, {chance=1, condition_values=[], max_level=27, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=27}], max_chance=5, version={name=emerald, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/9/}}]}, {location_area={name=hoenn-safari-zone-se, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/location-area/432/}, version_details=[{encounter_details=[{chance=4, condition_values=[], max_level=25, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=25}, {chance=1, condition_values=[], max_level=27, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=27}], max_chance=5, version={name=ruby, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/7/}}, {encounter_details=[{chance=4, condition_values=[], max_level=25, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=25}, {chance=1, condition_values=[], max_level=27, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=27}], max_chance=5, version={name=sapphire, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/8/}}, {encounter_details=[{chance=4, condition_values=[], max_level=25, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=25}, {chance=1, condition_values=[], max_level=27, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=27}], max_chance=5, version={name=emerald, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/9/}}]}, {location_area={name=kalos-route-3-area, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/location-area/714/}, version_details=[{encounter_details=[{chance=4, condition_values=[], max_level=4, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=4}, {chance=1, condition_values=[], max_level=5, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=5}], max_chance=5, version={name=x, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/23/}}, {encounter_details=[{chance=4, condition_values=[], max_level=4, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=4}, {chance=1, condition_values=[], max_level=5, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=5}], max_chance=5, version={name=y, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/24/}}]}, {location_area={name=santalune-forest-area, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/location-area/734/}, version_details=[{encounter_details=[{chance=5, condition_values=[], max_level=3, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=3}, {chance=1, condition_values=[], max_level=4, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=4}], max_chance=6, version={name=x, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/23/}}, {encounter_details=[{chance=5, condition_values=[], max_level=3, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=3}, {chance=1, condition_values=[], max_level=4, method={name=walk, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/1/}, min_level=4}], max_chance=6, version={name=y, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/24/}}]}, {location_area={name=slateport-city-contest-hall, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/location-area/781/}, version_details=[{encounter_details=[{chance=100, condition_values=[], max_level=20, method={name=gift, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/18/}, min_level=20}], max_chance=100, version={name=omega-ruby, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/25/}}, {encounter_details=[{chance=100, condition_values=[], max_level=20, method={name=gift, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/18/}, min_level=20}], max_chance=100, version={name=alpha-sapphire, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/26/}}]}, {location_area={name=verdanturf-town-contest-hall, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/location-area/782/}, version_details=[{encounter_details=[{chance=100, condition_values=[], max_level=20, method={name=gift, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/18/}, min_level=20}], max_chance=100, version={name=omega-ruby, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/25/}}, {encounter_details=[{chance=100, condition_values=[], max_level=20, method={name=gift, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/18/}, min_level=20}], max_chance=100, version={name=alpha-sapphire, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/26/}}]}, {location_area={name=fallarbor-town-contest-hall, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/location-area/783/}, version_details=[{encounter_details=[{chance=100, condition_values=[], max_level=20, method={name=gift, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/18/}, min_level=20}], max_chance=100, version={name=omega-ruby, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/25/}}, {encounter_details=[{chance=100, condition_values=[], max_level=20, method={name=gift, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/18/}, min_level=20}], max_chance=100, version={name=alpha-sapphire, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/26/}}]}, {location_area={name=lilycove-city-contest-hall, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/location-area/784/}, version_details=[{encounter_details=[{chance=100, condition_values=[], max_level=20, method={name=gift, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/18/}, min_level=20}], max_chance=100, version={name=omega-ruby, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/25/}}, {encounter_details=[{chance=100, condition_values=[], max_level=20, method={name=gift, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/18/}, min_level=20}], max_chance=100, version={name=alpha-sapphire, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/26/}}]}, {location_area={name=alola-route-1-east, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/location-area/1035/}, version_details=[{encounter_details=[{chance=15, condition_values=[], max_level=3, method={name=sos-encounter, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/33/}, min_level=2}], max_chance=15, version={name=ultra-sun, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/29/}}, {encounter_details=[{chance=15, condition_values=[], max_level=3, method={name=sos-encounter, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/33/}, min_level=2}], max_chance=15, version={name=ultra-moon, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/30/}}]}, {location_area={name=alola-route-1-west, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/location-area/1039/}, version_details=[{encounter_details=[{chance=15, condition_values=[], max_level=5, method={name=sos-encounter, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/33/}, min_level=3}], max_chance=15, version={name=sun, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/27/}}, {encounter_details=[{chance=15, condition_values=[], max_level=5, method={name=sos-encounter, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/33/}, min_level=3}], max_chance=15, version={name=moon, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/28/}}]}, {location_area={name=hauoli-city-shopping-district, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/location-area/1085/}, version_details=[{encounter_details=[{chance=15, condition_values=[], max_level=8, method={name=sos-encounter, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/33/}, min_level=5}], max_chance=15, version={name=sun, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/27/}}, {encounter_details=[{chance=15, condition_values=[], max_level=8, method={name=sos-encounter, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/33/}, min_level=5}], max_chance=15, version={name=moon, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/28/}}]}, {location_area={name=heahea-city-surf-association, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/location-area/1088/}, version_details=[{encounter_details=[{chance=100, condition_values=[], max_level=40, method={name=gift, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/18/}, min_level=40}], max_chance=100, version={name=ultra-sun, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/29/}}, {encounter_details=[{chance=100, condition_values=[], max_level=40, method={name=gift, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/encounter-method/18/}, min_level=40}], max_chance=100, version={name=ultra-moon, url=https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/30/}}]}]



@LHCHIN I don't think my answer deserves down vote. It was right
